# django cms - put existing plugin instance into placeholder

Tags: django-cms

The custom CMSPlugin `my_plugin` has been saved already.

Now, I would like to put it into the placeholder `my_placeholder`.

```
my_plugin.placeholder = my_placeholder
my_plugin.save()
```

leads to an empty plugin in `my_placeholder` although `my_plugin` has content.

What steps do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
my_plugin.placeholder = my_placeholder
my_plugin.plugin_type = CMSPluginBase_ChildClass
my_plugin.language = 'en'
my_plugin.position = 0
my_plugin.save()
```

It is necessary to explicitly set the plugin type, because one CMSPlugin, i.e. one class inheriting from `CMSPlugin`, might serve for the configuration of several classes inheriting from `CMSPluginBase`.

I havn't tested if defining language and position is really necessary, but it's probably a good idea.